# Connect old Cinema Display (24") as 2nd Display to newest iMac?

Tags: macos, imac, display, displayport, cinema-display

I'm considering buying a new 27" iMac (current model sold now).  I still have a 24" Cinema display (mini display port) that I currently have connected to an older iMac.

Now I'm wondering if this will work on the Thunderbolt socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why it shouldn't. TB has the same connector that mini display port. So you won't even need an adapter.